# How to find Bitbucket Account UUID?

Tags: git, rest, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Since bitbucket no longer supported the use of username. We must instead use User uuid for accessing the bitbucket api's.

Depreciated or Earlier

> https://api.bitbucket.com/2.0/users/udayRatan

Latest

> https://api.bitbucket.com/2.0/users/558050:c0b72ad0-1cb5-4018-9cdc-0cde8492c443

Comment: Yes, and you provided a link to a JSON data that includes the UUID. What real life programming problem is in question?

Comment: I cant find the bitbucket uuid in bitbucket.org account setting or anywhere. So i need to find the bitbucket account uuid for accessing the api's

Comment: Hey @RatanUdayKumar, any luck so far on the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a GET request for a repository that you own and see your UUID listed under the `owner` attribute:

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/1team/moxie
```

Or you could possibly make a GET request for all team members of a team you're a part of and see their UUID's there

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/teams/1team/members
```

Info taken from https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/uri-uuid#repo-obj

Comment: What do you mean "1team" for teamname? What if the repo does not belong to a team? And what to you mean "moxie" for repo-name? Is it just the name of repo, such as "my-xx-application"? What if other people have the same repo-name?

Answer (score 7):

1. Inspect your https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/
2. Search "uuid" in your browser inspector element
3. Enjoy your personal information (including uuid)

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe it could be this hard to get my own UUID.  The way i fixed it was to create a public repo and then run this curl command

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<bitbucketusername>/testrepo
```

the ouput contained my UUID.  I then obviously deleted the unsafe public repo.

Answer (score 0):

When using authenticated access you can make a GET request to `/2.0/user` and you will get the authenticated user's information:

`$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/user`

You need the value of `account_id` to access the API resources.

From: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/user

Comment: What's the value `$TOKEN` in this request? Where do you get it from?

Answer (score 0):

On the BitBucket repository page, and in the Pull Requests view, you can filter PRs by yourself and check the URL for the `author` query parameter.

i.e `https://bitbucket.org/workspace/repository/pull-requests/?state=ALL&author=%7B<UUID>%7D`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

See your bitbucket repository/admin.
Click to advance.

ex: https://bitbucket.org/seunggabi/test/admin

[image]

Comment: That is not the UUID of the user but that of the repository.